# ActiveRecord has_many through inverse_of causing rails admin to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-admin

I understand that in ActiveRecord for has_many :through associations don't work with inverse_of, yet I was encounter a problem with my has many through model in the Rails Admin gem where when I tried to edit or create a new resource, loading that page caused an infinite recursion of template rendering.

The question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633705/rails-admin-has-many-through-relationship-causing-infinite-rendering-of-templat)

When I tried removing

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipes, allow_destroy: true
```

it worked and the error went away.

But also it worked when I kept accepts_nested_attributes_for and placed

```
has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_categorizations, :inverse_of => :categories
```

:inverse_of at the end.

How is this possible? Isn't inverse_of unavailable for :through? Does it's presence cause any harm or is it just ignored?

I'm using Rails 4 if it's any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not set the `:inverse_of` record, the association will do its best to match itself up with the correct inverse. Automatic inverse detection only works on `has_many`, `has_one`, and `belongs_to` associations.

Extra options on the associations, as defined in the `AssociationReflection::INVALID_AUTOMATIC_INVERSE_OPTIONS` constant, will also prevent the association's inverse from being found automatically.

The automatic guessing of the inverse association uses a heuristic based on the name of the class, so it may not work for all associations, especially the ones with non-standard names.

Here is the [source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations) for setting inverses.

Comment: But why would it cause Rails admin to correctly identify the inverse if it doesn't work for :through? Is there any harm keeping it for the purposes of rails admin?